# image background in full slider bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Full Slider bootstrap [here](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/) and when I replace the image url by a image in a folder it does not work.

```
image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&... One')
```

by

```
<img class="fill" src="background:url(./img/header.jpg)"></img>
```

On the bootstrap page, some guys had the same issues even if I tried different solution ../img or /img, it does not work.

Someone has a idea ?

thank you

here is the source code from Bootstrap, I changed

```
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
```

by

```
<div class="fill" src="img/header.jpg"></div>
```

```html
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style=""></div>
                <div class="fill" src="img/header.jpg"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
   
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </header>
```

Comment: On the bootstrap page they dont use an img-tag, they use a div-tag, maybe this would fix it?

Comment: I tried, does not work.. @DominikNoll

Comment: Where do you have your html, and where is your image? 
Can you add the folder-structur ? 
@YLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work on local with this:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url('img/picture.jpg')"></div>
```

Inside the wrapper DIV

```
<!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
       <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('img/picture.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Caption 1</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!! Working perfectly!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this.
src = "img/header.jpg"